# Changing data in Array that contains array

Tags: arrays, swift, struct

i have a collectionView that contains this data

```
struct ImageModel {
    var images: String
    var imageLabel: String
    var description: String
    var comment = [String]()
}

class Model {
    var imageModel = [
        ImageModel(images: "1", imageLabel: "MDA", description: "Description", comment: ["First comment", "Next comment"]),
        ImageModel(images: "2", imageLabel: "Picture!", description: "Description", comment: []),
]
}
```

Then, i have a method that shows me detail info of this cell.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let vc = DetailVC()
        vc.picture = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: String(self.cell.imageModel[indexPath.row].images)))
        vc.productLabel.text = self.cell.imageModel[indexPath.row].imageLabel
        vc.comments = self.cell.imageModel[indexPath.row].comment
        vc.pictureNamed = self.cell.imageModel[indexPath.row].images
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
```

I need to add some comments on DetailVC() and save it to userDefaults.But I don't understand how to keep track of which specific index I'm currently on.

code on DetailVC(). Here is properties and textfield

```
//MARK: - Properties
    var model = Model()
    var picture = UIImageView()
    var comments = [String]()
    var pictureNamed = String()

var textFieldComment: UITextField = {
        let textField = UITextField()
        textField.placeholder = "add Comment"
        textField.borderStyle = .roundedRect
        return textField
    }()
```

Method to add comment

```
@objc func addComment() {
        if self.textFieldComment.text != "" {
            self.comments.append(self.textFieldComment.text!)
            self.userDefaultsComment.saveData(str: self.comments)
        }
        self.textFieldComment.text = ""
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Here i add comment to current VC, not to current Index of Array in array. Pls help..(

Answer (score 1):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let vc = DetailVC()
        vc.model = imageModel[indexPath.row]
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}

struct ImageModel:Identifiable {
    let id:String = UUID().uuidString
    var images: String
    var imageLabel: String
    var description: String
    
    var comments:[String] {
        return UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: id) as? [String] ?? []
    }
}

class Model {
    var imageModel = [
        ImageModel(images: "1", imageLabel: "MDA", description: "Description"),
        ImageModel(images: "2", imageLabel: "Picture!", description: "Description"),
    ]

}

class DetailVC:UIViewController {
    
    var model:ImageModel? {
        didSet {
            guard let model = model else {
                return
            }
            let picture = model.images
            let imagelebel = model.imageLabel
            let desc = model.description
            let _comments = model.comments
            self.comments = _comments
        }
    }
    
    var comments:[String] = [] {
        didSet {
            guard let model = model else {
                return
            }
            UserDefaults.standard.set(comments, forKey: model.id)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    var textFieldComment: UITextField = {
        let textField = UITextField()
        textField.placeholder = "add Comment"
        textField.borderStyle = .roundedRect
        return textField
    }()
    
    @objc func addComment() {
        if let text = textFieldComment.text, !text.isEmpty {
            self.comments.append(self.textFieldComment.text!)
            self.textFieldComment.text = ""
        }
    }

}
```